# Probability equation using arc4random()?

Tags: ios, math, probability, arc4random

In my game I know I can use conditions for this, but I wanted to see if there was a math equation that would make it easier on me. I'd like to use [`arc4random()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man3/arc4random.3.html).

What I need is:

1. If my score is 1-20, probability: 1 out of 25
2. If my score is 21-40, probability: 1 out of 20
3. If my score is 41-60, probability: 1 out of 15
4. If my score is 60+, probability: 1 out of 10.

Is this possible? And if so, how would I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use `arc4random_uniform(probability)`? It guarantees uniform distribution below the passed value, so a 1 out of 10 would be `arc4random_uniform(10) == 0` (the 0 can be any number below 10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick (hope it's clear!):

```
int modNumber = 25;
float alteredScore = score - (floor((score-1)/60) - 1) * 60;
modNumber -= floor((alteredScore-1)/20) * 5;
int result = arc4random() % modNumber;  // Or arc4random_uniform(modNumber) if you want to completely remove modulo bias, but beaing in mind the non-randomness (!) of arc4random and the size of modNumber I highly doubt it would make any real difference
if (!result) {
    // Result is 0
    // Do stuff for the lucky person
} else {
    // Make them miserable
}
```

Comment: Internally my best guess is that it does a similar thing. You would still need to calculate the mod number as above to work out what the probability is, and I can't imagine using `arc4random_uniform()` would be much faster. Plus I don't know if it's available for iOS.

Comment: Looking at the docs, `arc4random_uniform()` avoids modulo bias, but you're dealing with such small mod numbers that it hardly matters. Use whichever you want.

Comment: Just so I understand your comments, "Result is 0" means that the number was not chosen and "Make them miserable" is the chance number was chosen. Right?

Comment: I just also realized that in your second line, I get expected ; at end of declaration even though I did exactly as you did: float alteredScore -= (floor((score-1)/60) - 1) * 60;

Comment: Result is 0 means the 1 in whatever returned true. You could just as easily check for any number up to 14. Editing answer to fix other problem (whoops!).

Comment: Great - just let me know of any other problems you encounter!